# How to select Python Tuple/Dictionary Values where Index > x

Tags: python

How do you select python Tuple/Dictionary values where the index is greater than some number. I would think the code should look similar to the following assuming we create a Tuple:

`dt = (100, 200, 300,400)
 dt[dt.index > 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just slice the tuple.

```
>>> dt = (100, 200, 300,400)
>>> dt[2:]
(300, 400)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use : instead of > in tuples. like the answer ahsanul haque provided. thumbs up for him.